# Python program not performing as intended (beginner Rock Paper Scissor)

Tags: python

```
import random
print "Welcome to Rock, Papeeer, Scissor!"
name = raw_input("What's your name?")
print "Welcome %s" % name
rounds = raw_input("How many rounds you want to play?")
rps_choice = ['R', 'P', 'S']

def rps(r,p,s):
    x = 0 
    hs = 0
    cs = 0
    draw = 0
    while x < int(rounds):
        computer_choice = random.choice (rps_choice)
        human_choice = raw_input("Choose (R)ock, (P)aper, or (S)cissor?")
        human_choice.upper()

        print "Computer choose : %s" %computer_choice
        print computer_choice
        if computer_choice == 'r' and human_choice == 's' or computer_choice == 's' and human_choice == 'p' or computer_choice == 'p' and human_choice == 'r':
            print "computer wins"
            print "Ha Ha Ha looser, Sachin fails."
            cs = cs + 1
            print "Computer score : %d" % cs 
            print "Human score : %d"  % hs
        elif computer_choice == human_choice:
            print "Its a draw"
            draw = draw + 1
        else :
            print "You won %s" % name
            hs = hs + 1
            print "Computer score %d:" % cs 
            print "Human score : %d" % hs
            x = x + 1
    print "Final score is Computer : %d and %s : %d" % (cs, name, hs)
    if hs > cs:
        print "You won, Sachin is the greatest player ever born."
    elif hs == cs:
        print "Its a draw"
    else:
        print "Muhahahaha Sachin ki aisi ki taisi, you lost."
rps('R', 'P', 'S')
```

Now, it runs fine but no matter what input user give, user always wins. There is not even a draw (even when the choices are same as intended). For example :

```
Welcome to Rock, Papeeer, Scissor!
What's your name?Alpha
Welcome Alpha
How many rounds you want to play?3
Choose (R)ock, (P)aper, or (S)cissor?s
Computer choose : R
R
You won Alpha
Computer score 0:
Human score : 1
Choose (R)ock, (P)aper, or (S)cissor?p
Computer choose : P
P
You won Alpha
Computer score 0:
Human score : 2
Choose (R)ock, (P)aper, or (S)cissor?r
Computer choose : P
P
You won Alpha
Computer score 0:
Human score : 3
Final score is Computer : 0 and Alpha : 3
You won, Sachin is the greatest player ever born.
bash-4.2$
```

Well Computer should had won the first and last round while the second should had been a draw but no matter what user always wins here.

Now I have managed to run this program fine (thanks to stackoverflow only) by looking at other similar programs but my code has been drastically changed in the process, so I am looking for "what is causing the error" in my program rather than a solution for the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings are immutable, and the `str.upper()` method returns a **new** string object. You are ignoring that here:

```
human_choice.upper()
```

You want to store the result:

```
human_choice = human_choice.upper()
```

However, you are then proceeding to test all the options against **lowercase** characters:

```
if computer_choice == 'r' and human_choice == 's' or computer_choice == 's' and human_choice == 'p' or computer_choice == 'p' and human_choice == 'r':
```

You need to make up your mind here. Either lowercase all input, or uppercase all input, then use the appropriate case in your tests too!

Rather than test every possible combination, look up what each user choice beats by using a mapping:

```
beats = {'R': 'S', 'S': 'P', 'P': 'R'}

if beats[human_choice] == computer_choice:
    # human wins!
elif beats[computer_choice] == human_choice
    # computer wins!
else:
    # assume a draw
```

`beats['R']` (rock) returns `'S'`, scissors, etc. This is then easily extended, so you can play [Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard, Spock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock-paper-scissors-lizard-Spock) too, without having to write out all 10 winning combinations by hand:

```
beats {
    'rock': {'lizard', 'scissors'},
    'paper': {'rock', 'spock'},
    'scissors': {'paper', 'lizard'},
    'lizard': {'spock', 'paper'},
    'spock': {'scissors', 'rock'},
}

if computer_choice in beats[human_choice]:
    # human won
# etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

`upper` does not modify the string in place, you need to use the returned value to assign it to something. For this line

```
human_choice.upper()
```

You could do

```
human_choice = human_choice.upper()
```

For example, look at this demo

```
>>> letter = 'a'
>>> letter
'a'
>>> letter.upper()
'A'
>>> letter
'a'           # Notice that letter has not been modified
>>> letter = letter.upper()
>>> letter
'A'           # Now it has
```